# Why does pytrends give zero (0) values for all search Index of certain words?

Tags: python-3.x, google-trends

I get zero values for all search terms with pytrends. I have been using pytrends for months now, and for these particular terms, I got none zero values yesterday morning. It started showing me zeros from evening to this point. Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

I tried getting the google trends by region for the search terms ['MeTV', 'Story Television', 'Court TV', 'GOD TV', 'MyNetworkTV']. It gives zero values for all countries. This result is false as checking it manually on google trends gives non-zero values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reply could be a bit late, but we got the same trouble while using PyTrends. Curves tend to NULL for some requests from time to time (whereas the Goole Trends results were still valid), and the region-based search results were just inconsistent (mainly out of the US zone). Two strategies could be applied to solve the problem to the best of my knowledge (i) to enter into the deep / the code of PyTrends (we skip this ....) (ii) to develop your own Google Trends scraper.

This is not a big deal, with a bit of GUI automation (e.g. AutoGUI if you're coding in Python). We have been successful to collect consistent data with Google Trends (including specific / region searches). Also, our global request throughput increases a bit (from 12 to around 9 seconds per request). A nice key point too, Google Trends provides just a part of the SEO information (for the traffic estimation) that has to be combined with others sources for the SEO difficulty. APIs (such as PyTrends) are not still available in most cases, GUI automation makes sense to scrap all the data in one shot.

Some reports (in French) if it could help

http://mathieu.delalandre.free.fr/training/pgl-2022-2023.pdf

http://mathieu.delalandre.free.fr/training/projetdev-2021-2022-2.pdf

http://mathieu.delalandre.free.fr/training/internship2022-aureliensegura.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mathieu. I've been offline for a while. I had eventually had to build a scraper for that.